# Converting 16bit to float

Tags: convert

I am trying to communicate with AT30TS75A-MA8M-T with below code, the problem is converting the 16 bit output to float so I can read temp:

Base on [data sheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8839-DTS-AT30TS75A-Datasheet.pdf)
[image]
I suppose to remove first 5 bit in order to read correctly but I am not converting it correctly.

Ex: (0b001001001100000 AND 0 b0111111111100000) = 0b1001001100000
0b1001001100000 >> 5 = 0b10010011 = 147

```
    void Atemp::begin()
{

    Wire.begin();

    // Check if sensor temp sensor is avilable

    // if (mySensor.beginI2C() == false)
    // {
    //     data[9] = 5; // Error Code
    // }
    // Set registor for two decimal
    Wire.beginTransmission(_i2cAddress);
    Wire.write(1);
    Wire.write(0b01100000);
    Wire.endTransmission();
}

void Atemp::read()
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(_i2cAddress);
    Wire.write(0);
    result = Wire.endTransmission();
    // result is 0-4
    if (result != 0)
    {
        data[9] = 5; // Error Code
    }

    result = Wire.requestFrom(_i2cAddress, (uint8_t)2);
    if (result != 2)
    {
        data[9] = 5; // Error Code
    }
    else
    {
        uint8_t part1 = Wire.read();
        uint8_t part2 = Wire.read();
        
        data[7] = part1;
         data[8] = part2;
        int16_t rawval = (part1 << 8 | part2) ;
        // rawval >>= 6;
        float temp = rawval / 256.0f;
        floatconv(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Right-shift the data to align it to the right of the variable, and
2. Multiply it by the value of one bit.

When right shifting be sure to do it in a *signed* data type so that C will *sign extend* the value and retain any negativeness to the value.

So taking the 12-bit examples from the datasheet you right shift 4 bits, so

```
SDDDDDDDDDDD0000
```

becomes

```
SSSSSDDDDDDDDDDD
```

(where S is the sign bit and D is a valid data bit, and 0 is padding)

Then simply multiply the value by 0.0625 to get the actual temperature.

In code that might look like:

```cpp
int16_t rawval = part1 << 8 | part2;
rawval >>= 4; // Do this in the int16_t to preserve the sign
float temperature = rawval * 0.0625;
```

For different resolutions right shift by different amounts and multiply by the appropriate single-bit value for that resolution (hint: 11 bit is double the value of 12 bit, 10 bit is double the value of 11 bit, etc).

Comment: @Shahreza Page 10 of the datasheet. `The resolution of the temperature measurement data can be configured to 9, 10, 11, or 12 bits which corresponds to
temperature increments of 0.5̊C, 0.25̊C, 0.125̊C, and 0.0625̊C, respectively. `

Answer (score 3):

Just a complement to Majenko's answer. The temperature register is set
in such a way that you can interpret it in the same way irrespective of
the selected resolution:

```cpp
int16_t rawval = part1 << 8 | part2;
float temperature = rawval * (1/256.0);
```

Comment: Good plan - didn't think of that ;)